# Add anchor class in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

How can i add anchor class in codeigniter

This is normal html tag:

```
<a class="tooltips" href="index.html"><span>Log out</span><i class="lnr lnr-power-switch"></i></a>
```

But when i add class="tooltips" it comes out of a tag:

```
<?php echo anchor('User_Controller/settings','class="tooltips"<span>Logout</span><i class="lnr lnr-power-switch"></i>');?>
```

This is what i get:

```
<a href="http://localhost/qms/index.php/User_Controller/settings">class="tooltips"<span>Logout</span><i class="lnr lnr-power-switch"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error, you can try this ,

`<?php echo anchor('User_Controller/settings', '<span>Logout</span><i class="lnr lnr-power-switch"></i>', 'class="tooltips"'); ?>`

for refference : [Ancher helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#anchor)

Answer (score 0):

```
$atts = array(
    'width'       => 800,
    'height'      => 600,
    'scrollbars'  => 'yes',
    'status'      => 'yes',
    'resizable'   => 'yes',
    'screenx'     => 0,
    'screeny'     => 0,
    'window_name' => '_blank'
    'class' => 'btn btn-primary'
);
echo anchor('news/local/123', 'Click Me!', $atts); //it's example
```